# Change Straight quotes to Smart quotes without sacrificing word wrap

Tags: text-processing

How to change straight quotes to smart curly quotes without omitting word wrap.

The example contains single straight quote and double straight quotes.

**INPUT**

```
1 I have bowed before only one sanyasi in my life, and that is 'Sri
2 Chandrasekharendra Saraswathi', known to the world as the "Parmacharya."
3 
4 Therefore, I was the ''modern 
5 Indian'',believer in science, and
6 with little concern for spiritual
7 diversions.
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 I have bowed before only one sanyasi in my life, and that is ‘Sri
2 Chandrasekharendra Saraswathi’, known to the world as the “Parmacharya.”
3 
4 Therefore, I was the “modern 
5 Indian”,believer in science, and with
6 little concern for spiritual 
7 diversions.
```

Comment: it would be good if you have shown the expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have added expected result.

Comment: Word processors seem to follow simple rules: straight-quote followed by letter → left quote, so did you try regular expressions (eg `sed`)?

Comment: @likkachu some scripts wouldn't  turn straight quotes to curly when newline occured in between.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen No I didnt  try sed. But it can be done. I also found a simple solution. It employs pandoc `pandoc --wrap=preserve  -f markdown -t markdown -S filename` option `-S` changes staright quotes to curly ones.

Answer (score 2):

To make the newlines a non-issue, we could do a replacement so that a whole paragraph or the whole file is processed as one string. With Perl, we could use `-0777` to read the full file at one go, or `-00` to use paragraph mode (i.e. sections separated by empty lines, that would of course require that the line numbers are not part of the input file):

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/\x27\x27/"/g; s/\x27(.*?)\x27/‘$1’/gs; s/"(.*?)"/“$1”/gs; ' input
I have bowed before only one sanyasi in my life, and that is ‘Sri
Chandrasekharendra Saraswathi’, known to the world as the “Parmacharya.”

Therefore, I was the “modern 
Indian”, believer in science, and
with little concern for spiritual
diversions.
```

I used the hex representation `\x27` of the single-quote to make the quoting easier. `.*?` means any string, but the shortest possible match. The first rule changes doubled single-quotes `''` to double-quotes.

Or, similarly with GNU sed, `-z` takes the input as NUL-separated strings, so a usual text file will be read in one go:

```
$ sed -zEe 's/\x27\x27/"/g; s/\x27([^\x27]*)\x27/‘\1’/g; s/"([^"]*)"/“\1”/g; ' input
I have bowed before only one sanyasi in my life, and that is ‘Sri
Chandrasekharendra Saraswathi’, known to the world as the “Parmacharya.”

Therefore, I was the “modern 
Indian”, believer in science, and
with little concern for spiritual
diversions.
```

Comment: This only works when all quotes are balanced. One should check if this is the case before using these scripts.

Comment: @helcim, yeah, well, there's really nothing we can do about unbalanced/missing quotes, there's no way for a program to decide what the correct quoting should be, so it's a "garbage in-garbage out" situation. The bigger issue which I've totally neglected here is that the single-quote/apostrophe can well appear in contractions, and that's even a reasonable use-case. But detecting them programmatically would also be somewhat difficult.

Comment: Indeed. That's why perhaps it would be more practical not to replace quotations using captures but only use preceding and following character for tests whether to use left or right quote.

Comment: @helcim, Point. I don't have time to test and write that now, but it does sound like something you could write up as an answer yourself. :)

Comment: I will have to do it, that's why I came to this place ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution. It employs `pandoc` like this, where the option `-S` changes straight quotes to curly ones:

```
pandoc --wrap=preserve -f markdown -t markdown -S <filename>
```

<sup>Taken from [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363491/change-straight-quotes-to-smart-quotes-without-sacrificing-word-wrap#comment644893_363491) by [Ramaprakasha](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/102981/ramaprakasha)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A naive implementation which relies entirely on Perl's word character class. Changes only ["] to [„] or [”].

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w -0777
local $/ = undef;

open INFILE, $ARGV[0] or die "I can't read the file. $!";
$string =  <INFILE>;
close INFILE;

$string =~ s/(\w)\"/$1”/smg;
$string =~ s/\"(\w)/„$1/smg;

open OUTFILE, ">",   $ARGV[1] or die "I can't write to the file. $!";
print OUTFILE ($string);

close
```

Save as `script.pl` and run `perl script.pl INFILE OUTFILE`. After that you only have to search for any left over incorrectly placed straight quotes like |aaaaaa"bbbbb| or |aaaa " bbbb| which hopefully are not very frequent.