# How Can I Replace Straight Quotes With Curly Quotes

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I would like to replace straight single and double quotes with curly quotes (`‘ ’`, `“ ”`).
How can I do this with a shell command?

Comment: How can one distinguish between opening and closing quote? odd = opening, even = closing? Can there be nested quotes? Will the input always contain quotes in pairs? Can you distinguish between single quote and apostrophe? Can there be something like `A text about quote characters ('"') may contain quotes that don't come in pairs.` Please [edit] your question to answer. Add a sufficiently complicated example of input and expected output.

Comment: @doneal24 They don't want to replace single with double quotes, but straight with curly quotes.

Comment: Similar, if not a duplicate: [Change Straight quotes to Smart quotes without sacrificing word wrap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/363491)

Comment: @Kusalananda that does not actually work. I tried all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using this input file (courtesy of [Burns](http://www.robertburns.org.uk/Assets/Poems_Songs/tamoshanter.htm)):

```
$ cat file
When 'chapmen billies' lea "the street" and 'drouthy' neebors "neebors" meet.
```

and any awk:

```
awk '{
    while ( match($0,/\047[^\047]*\047/) ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) "‘" substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2) "’" substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    while ( match($0,/"[^"]*"/) ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) "“" substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2) "”" substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}' file
When ‘chapmen billies’ lea “the street” and ‘drouthy’ neebors “neebors” meet.
```

The above assumes your quotes are always in matched pairs.

Comment: I need something that works when quotes are not matched in pairs. For example: "Linux programmer's manual".

Comment: Then edit your question to provide sample input/output **that covers all of your use cases** and explain how we should determine which quote to use where.

Comment: The question makes it pretty clear that I want to replace all straight single and double quotes with the curly version. It did not say **paired** quotes.

Comment: @Amarakon Instead of arguing you should improve your question by adding clarification and example input and output. Even if it is clear *to you* that you mean all quotes, paired or not, apparently it is not clear to the people who try to help you.

Comment: @Amarakon it didn't say paired quotes but it also doesn't state how to decide which type of "smart quote" to use in place of any given unpaired quote nor does it state how to identify 2 unpaired quotes differently from 1 set of paired quotes which is why it's reasonable to assume you meant paired quotes since the behavior you want for unpaired quotes is unspecified.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl` and in UTF-8 locales:

```
perl -C -0777 -pi.back -e '
  s/\N{QUOTATION MARK}(.*?)\N{QUOTATION MARK}/\N{LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK}$1\N{RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK}/gs;
  s/\N{APOSTROPHE}(.*?)\N{APOSTROPHE}/\N{LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK}$1\N{RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK}/gs
  ' your-files
```

(original backed-up with a `.back` suffix. Remove the `.back` if you don't care about backup).